# I added a mobile column in auth_user in postgres(working on django).But getting error:User() got an unexpected keyword argument 'mobile'

Tags: python, django, postgresql

This is my views.py

```
 from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
 from django.conf.urls import url
 from .models import Category,Product
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User, auth

 def signup(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        first_name=request.POST['first_name']
        last_name=request.POST['last_name']
        email=request.POST['email']
        mobile=request.POST['mobile']
        password=request.POST['password']
        cpassword=request.POST['cpassword']

    user=User.objects.create_user(first_name=first_name,last_name=last_name,email=email,mobile=mobile,password=password)

    user.save();
    
    return redirect('/')

else:
    return render(request,"signup.html")
```

I added a column directly in postgres named mobile and didnt make any kind of changes in django regarding that.Please help me in proceeding

Answer (score 0):

You cannot create a column directly in your database and expect that the Django ORM magically gets aware of it. The error itself is self explanatory, the constructor for the User model doesn't have a keyword argument `"mobile"` defined. You need to create your custom model that extends from the base `AbstractBaseUser` model, or create a model with additional data that has a `OneToOne` relationship with your user model.

The Django docs have a page explaining how to do this with a full example: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model

Comment: I went to these docs earlier but wasnt able to find that section that would be helpful to me.Can you please tell the section in these docs that would solve my problem

Comment: At the end you have a full example extending the AbstractBaseUser where it adds a custom date_of_birth field and also creates the custom views for creating and updating the model.

If you prefer the other method (using a OneToOne relationship), here's a tutorial explaining how to do so: https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/22/how-to-extend-django-user-model.html